# How to call getSupportFragmentManager() when trying to Navigate to fragment from Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

`I am calling Recycler Adapter from Fragment not from acvity`.

When I click on Item in `Recyclerview`, I want to navigate to another `Fragment`.

So for that I have written `onClickListner()` in `Adapter`.

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener(final int position){
    return new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{

                activityType = context.getActivityFragmentTag(EmpConstants.WorkType.Entry);
                fragment = new Entry_Fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, activityType)
                        .commit();



            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("eEmp/StnFailAdapter","Excp due to"+e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But it is showing error at `getSupportFragmentManager();`

[image: When I click on item in the recyclerview, I need to navigate to fragment]

Comment: What kind of error? Can you update the question with this error?

Comment: updated the question Please check@OscarCaballeroPozas

Comment: Write context.getSupportedFragmentManger() ;

Comment: @vishnu What is your Activity Name? And do you have reference of Context in your Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*getSupportFragmentManager()* is a method from `AppCompatActivity`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity#getSupportFragmentManager()

If you use Fragment from support lib (extending `AppCompatActivity`) you need replace for this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

or use Fragment from Android SDK:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: I have used support lib. But FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(); is not working